# TypeError when trying to parse fortnite-api response

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests

I'm trying to get the fortnite-api website data and only get the things listed under "emote"

```
r = requests.get('https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br', headers=headers)

rr = r.json()
for sub_dict in rr['data']:
    for image_sub_dict in sub_dict['type']:
      for j in image_sub_dict['value']:
          print(j)
```

This results in `TypeError: string indices must be integers | Json data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not parsing the data correctly.

The line `for image_sub_dict in sub_dict['type']:` will be returning the keys of the `'type'` dict, not the values. Instead you probably just want to query the `'type'` dict for the value of `"emote"`. Here's an example of getting an icon url for all of the emotes:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(
    'https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br', 
    headers={'Accept': 'application/json'},
).json()

for entry in response['data']:
    kind = entry['type']['value']
    if kind  == 'emote':
        name = entry['name']
        icon = entry['images']['icon']
        print(f"{name}: {icon}")
```

Output:

```
...
Scorecard: https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/eid_scorecard/icon.png
Team Burger: https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/eid_scorecardburger/icon.png
Team Tomato: https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/eid_scorecardtomato/icon.png
Members Only: https://fortnite-api.com/images/cosmetics/br/eid_secrethandshake/icon.png
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some logging to see which key is wrong.  Try:

```
rr = r.json()
print(rr, type(rr))
for sub_dict in rr['data']:
    print(sub_dict, type(sub_dict))
    for image_sub_dict in sub_dict['type']:
      print(image_sub_dict, type(image_sub_dict))
      for j in image_sub_dict['value']:
          print(j)
```